# Useful statistics from Pi Pico

Tags: pi-pico, micropython

Apart from reading the internal temperature sensor and frequency, is there any other useful information you can query on the Pico board using Micropython?

For example, memory or flash usage, CPU usage etc.

Comment: No one but you can know which information you think is useful.  You need to read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory usage can be measured in the same way as ordinary Python, [using `gc.alloc()` and `gc.free()`](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/gc.html).

Flash usage likewise be measured using [`os.statvfs('/')`](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/os.html#os.statvfs).

I'm not aware of any way of getting the CPU usage. The only thing that comes to mind is `machine.freq()`, which will tell you the CPU frequency.

You can test these with:

```py
import gc
import os
import machine

s = os.statvfs('/')
print(f"Free storage: {s[0]*s[3]/1024} KB")
print(f"Memory: {gc.mem_alloc()} of {gc.mem_free()} bytes used.")
print(f"CPU Freq: {machine.freq()/1000000}Mhz")
```

It's worth having a look through [the MicroPython libraries docs](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/index.html) as there may be other hidden gems there.

Answer (score 0):

mem_info() gives a lot of information with very little code.

```
import micropython
micropython.meminfo()
```

stack: 516 out of 7936
GC: total: 233472, used: 27536, free: 205936
No. of 1-blocks: 273, 2-blocks: 39, max blk sz: 211, max free sz: 4221

Calling it with

```
micropython.meminfo(True)
```

also shows a memory allocation map.